# OneDrive folders duplicated?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I bought the microsoft 365 subscription to get 1TB OneDrive. I think I've set something up wrong. In Windows Explorer, I dragged my Pictures folder to the OneDrive folder instead of setting up backups through the OneDrive icon in the notification bar. Now I'm culling old pictures in C:\users\username\Pictures\2014\Monterey by deleting from or moving them into that folder. They do not automatically get synced to OneDrive. I don't see them in the OneDrive\Pictures\2014\Monterey folder. In OneDrive settings, manage backup, it tells me that there are 7465 in the selected folders with the same name as files already in OneDrive. It wants to add -Copy to the filename and have both items in OneDrive. Do I need to somehow remove what's in OneDrive and start over?

Comment: @dave white Yes, the folders I want to sync are listed  in OneDrive settings. Also, I tried a test yesterday by deleting one picture in C:\users\username\Pictures\2014\Monterey and it still appears in OneDrive\Pictures\2014\Monterey

Answer (score 0):

> They do not automatically get synced to OneDrive. I don't see them in the OneDrive\Pictures\2014\Monterey folder. In OneDrive settings, manage backup, it tells me that there are 7465 in the selected folders with the same name as files already in OneDrive

Most likely it's a config problem. In OneDrive settings, go to the `Account` tab and click on `Choose folders`. Ensure that the folder(s) you want to sync is/are listed in there.

Otherwise you are just pushing files into the OneDrive cloud but not actually syncing them.